# Issue creating CNV plot from WES data

Tags: python, ngs, cnv, wes

I received Whole Exome Sequencing data from an NGS company (CARIS, specifically). I received R1 and R2 FASTQ files, a BAM file aligned to hg38, and a VCF file.

I used CNVPytor to create a CNV plot (Manhattan plot), by following this example Jupyter Notebook here: https://github.com/abyzovlab/CNVpytor/blob/master/examples/PythonLibraryGuide.ipynb

However, when I run this code on my data, I get the following graph:

[image: Graph1]

Furthermore, I tried to use CNVKit and used the following steps/code:

```
cnvkit.py batch TN21-116928.DNA.bam --normal -m hybrid --fasta hg38.fa --targets targets.bed --output-reference my_reference.cnn
```

Where "targets.bed" was a file of the following form:

```
chr1    33306766    33321098    A3GALT2
chr22   42692121    42721298    A4GALT
chr3    138123713   138132390   A4GNT
chr12   53307456    53324864    AAAS
chr12   125065434   125143333   AACS
chr3    151814073   151828488   AADAC
```

The graph created from this is the following:
[image: Graph 2]

Does anyone know where I am going wrong? Any pointers?

Comment: `cnvkit.py scatter -s Sample.cn{s,r} -c chr7` maybe? Anyway its a cool question (except for the results)